# Erro no include JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Servlet instanciada na raíz

/MinhaServlet

Jsp instanciado em uma pasta dentro da raíz:

> /pasta/arquivo.jsp

Dentro desse arquivo tenho o seguinte

```
<img src="_img/editar.png">
<a href="_global/topoErro.jsp">Editar</a>
<jsp:include page="_global/topoErro.jsp" /> </div>
```

Perceba que tanto a imagem quanto o link href estão apontando para pastas que estão na raiz da aplicação mas que deveriam estar com ../ antes pois este arquivo está em /pasta assim como /_img e /_global.

Minha dúvida é porque que o jsp include dá erro quando o uso da mesma forma que o href se o arquivos que esta no href e o arquivo que esta no jsp include são os mesmos?

```
_global,
_img
```

São pastas que estão na raiz!
E minha Servlet também esta anotada na raiz

```
@WebServlet(
            name="MinhaServlet", 
            urlPatterns={"/MinhaServlet"}
           )
```

Sem mensão no web.xml

No meu projeto está assim: Aqui estou tendo problemas para colar.
erro404.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="constantes" class="util.Constantes" />     
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>    
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/estiloSite.css" />
<title>${constantes.tituloSite}</title>
</head>
<body class="fadeIn">

 <div id="topo"> <jsp:include page="../_global/topoErro.jsp" /> </div>
 <div id="meio"> <jsp:include page="erro404Conteudo.jsp" /> </div>
 <div id="mapa"> <jsp:include page="../_global/mapaErro.jsp" /> </div>
 <div id="creditos"> <jsp:include page="../_global/creditosErro.jsp" /> </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

erro404Conteudo

```
<div id="central">

        Esta página não existe! <br/>
        Código do Erro : ${statusCode} <br/>
        <img src="_img/editar.png">
        <a href="_global/topoErro.jsp">Editar</a>
        <jsp:include page="_global/topoErro.jsp" />

</div>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54612/discussion-on-question-by-carlos-rocha-erro-no-include-jsp)

Answer (score 1):

Use o jstl:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<a href="<c:url value="/jsp/index.htm"/>">TEST</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o melhor é usar caminhos absolutos...

```
<img src="/SuaAplicação/_img/editar.png">

<a href="/SuaAplicação/_global/topoErro.jsp">Editar</a>

<jsp:include page="/_global/topoErro.jsp" /> </div>
```

Caso não queira usar caminho absoluto para os links HTML da página basta usar:

```
<img src="../_img/editar.png">

<a href="../_global/topoErro.jsp">Editar</a>
```

Mas, no include:jsp utilize o caminho começando apenas com '/'.

Obs.: Caso não queira declarar explicitamente o nome de sua aplicação para caminhos absolutos, pode ser usado **${pageContext.request.contextPath}** em sua JSP. =)